# How can I inject a class to 'Class<?> clazz' in Guice?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have a class with a constructor, e.g.:

```
@Inject
public ClassTest(ITestInterface testInterface, Class<?> clazz){
    ...
}
```

The problem is how do I bind a class to an implementation which can be injected in this constructor and will the `ClassTest` binding pick the right class?

I want to inject different classes at different point of time. When I attempted to solve it Guice gives an error that it cannot find any suitable constructor on `java.lang.Class`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use [assisted inject](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/AssistedInject) extension of Guice.

Basically, you define your `ClassTest` as it is, but mark 'varying' dependencies as `@Assisted`:

```
@Inject
public ClassTest(ITestInterface testInterface, @Assisted Class<?> clazz){
    ...
}
```

Then you create a factory interface for `ClassTest` objects which will accept `Class` argument and return `ClassTest`s:

```
public interface ClassTestFactory {
    ClassTest create(Class<?> clazz);
}
```

Then you install special kind of module which will create factories for you:

```
// Inside your module
install(new FactoryModuleBuilder().build(ClassTestFactory.class));
```

Then wherever you need `ClassTest` instances you should inject `ClassTestFactory` interface instead:

```
@Inject
YourLogicClass(ClassTestFactory ctFactory) {
    this.ctFactory = ctFactory;
}
```

And finally you use it to create `ClassTest`s for every class object you want:

```
ClassTest ct1 = ctFactory.create(SomeClass.class);
ClassTest ct2 = ctFactory.create(AnotherClass.class);
```

But if I were you, I would really reconsider the whole class architecture to avoid the need in such things.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved even without assisted inject, simply by using a `TypeLiteral` when creating the binding:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule;
import com.google.inject.Guice;
import com.google.inject.Injector;
import com.google.inject.Module;
import com.google.inject.TypeLiteral;

public class ClassTest
{
    static interface ITestInterface {}

    @Inject
    public ClassTest(ITestInterface testInterface, Class<?> clazz)
    {
        System.err.println("testInterface=" + testInterface);
        System.err.println("clazz=" + clazz);
    }

    public static void main(String... argument)
    {
        ITestInterface testObject = new ITestInterface() {};
        Module module = new AbstractModule()
        {
            @Override
            protected void configure()
            {
                binder().bind(ITestInterface.class).toInstance(testObject);
                binder().bind(new TypeLiteral<Class<?>>() {}).toInstance(testObject.getClass());
                //            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            }
        };
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(module);
        injector.getInstance(ClassTest.class);
    }
}
```

The output when running this code is something like:

```
testInterface=ClassTest$1@3d921e20
clazz=class ClassTest$1
```

I have to agree with @VladimirMatveev though, that this is a somewhat unusual use case, and that the need for injection of `java.lang.Class` objects might be indicative of a design flaw. The only seemingly valid case of this type of injection that I've come across is for type checking, where an injected class needs the `Class` object to check the type of some other object (via `Class.isInstance(...)`) but it is not desirable to inject an instance (!) of that class (e.g., because it is not a singleton and might spawn all sorts of other undesired object creations). Still, even that scenario is somewhat hokey and might be solvable in a better way.
At the very least, I would use a more specific type argument, like `Class<? extends ITestInterface>` (which, I suspect, is what's intended by the OP).

Answer (score -1):

To change injected value over time you could use the Provider [bindings](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ProviderBindings). And then it could look like this:

The module configuration:

```
public class SomeModule extends AbstractModule{

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(Class.class).toProvider(SomeProvider.class);

    }
}
```

The provider(not very elegant but may be for a start...):

```
public class SomeProvider implements Provider<Class<?>>{

    private static Class<?> myClazz;

    public static void setClass(Class<?> clazz){
        myClazz = clazz;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> get() {
        return myClazz;
    }

}
```

Some different classes:

```
public class SomeClass{
    public int itWorks;

}
public class SomeOtherClass{
    public int itWorksGreat;

}
```

Example client code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    SomeProvider.setClass(SomeClass.class);
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new SomeModule());
    printFields(injector.getInstance(Class.class));
    SomeProvider.setClass(SomeOtherClass.class);
    printFields(injector.getInstance(Class.class));
}
private static void printFields(Class clazz) {
    Field[] declaredFields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
    for(Field field : declaredFields){
        System.out.println(field.getName());
    }
}
```

And finally the result:

```
itWorks
itWorksGreat
```

Comment: You should *never ever* write such providers! It defies the whole reason of DI concept and really it is something which Guice tries to remove.

Comment: well... you are right (however it's still possible). +1 to your answer, it's really nice and I din not know about such solution. I think I could make use of it couple of problems that I had